# Scrape links according to their length

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape all the links of the pages with alphabetical names of this website:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

That is to say links like:

```
['/pinpai/2-a.html','/pinpai/3-b.html'...]
```

In order to scrape a few more things in these.

Following [this advanced webscraping tutorial](http://sangaline.com/post/advanced-web-scraping-tutorial/) I motivated myself to learn xpath filtering. As they seem to be less than 17 chars long and as I found some length filtering resources on a doc I tried to filter the links on their length in the following scrapy scraper's spider:

```
import scrapy

class NosetimeScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nosetime"
    start_urls = ['https://www.nosetime.com/pinpai/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # proceed to other pages of the listings
        for page_url in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "pinpai"), string-length(@href)<17]/@href').extract():
            print("page_url: ", page_url)
            page_url = response.urljoin(page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

But got:

```
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1582, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid predicate

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\DataScience\nosetime_scraper\nosetime_scraper\spiders\nosetime_spider.py", line 10, in parse
    for page_url in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "pinpai"), string-length(@href)<17]/@href').extract():
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\response\text.py", line 139, in xpath
    return self.selector.xpath(query, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 260, in xpath
    six.reraise(ValueError, ValueError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 256, in xpath
    **kwargs)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1582, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //a[contains(@href, "pinpai"), string-length(@href)<17]/@href
```

So how can I filter links I'm scraping according to their length? I also thought about their scructure {one or two digits} - {letter} but didn't found resources that would help me build that in the doc.

Comment: replace **,** in predicate with **and** "//a[contains(@href, "pinpai") and string-length(@href)<17]/@href"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct sintax of the XPath is

```
'//a[contains(@href, "pinpai") and string-length(@href)<17]/@href'
```

This line worked for me:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "pinpai") and string-length(@href)<17]/@href').extract()
```

FWIW you could also filter the links using regex, but I think the XPath above should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Damn, you could user regex in these filters?!